# What Java external packages/libraries out there?

Tags: java, package, external

I need to know what are the most **helpful**, **easy-to-use** packages out there for developing games in Java?

I need packages for:

- Network/Online
- Sound/Music
- 2D graphics (I'm not interested in 3D)
- Database

Comment: I think you should change the title of the question for  something like:  Java libraries for game development. It would be more descriptive

Comment: I'd like to edit the title, but I don't think I've the privileges to do that :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned you're not interested in 3D, but you ought to take a look at [LWJGL](http://www.lwjgl.org/). It handles access to OpenGL (which you can create a 2D renderer with), OpenAL (sound/music) and controllers (gamepads, etc).

Comment: Seems very interesting! Can you provide me some easy tutorial links plz?

Comment: Actually, while looking for a tutorial for you, I've found this library: [Slick](http://slick.cokeandcode.com), which is based on LWJGL and focus on 2D games. Its documentation wiki also has [some tutorials](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/wiki/doku.php?id=tutorials)

Answer (score 1):

For the Physics you can use:

http://www.jbox2d.org/

is a port from the  C physics engine box2d